# 'Where' statement in LinQ to Sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Hello i using LinQ to sql Link i need to gel list of items that have ParentID==X
 server code

```
  ul_LeftMenu.DataSource = data.TABLE_MENU_ITEMs.ToList();
  ul_LeftMenu.DataBind();
```

i need some think like this

```
      int id =3;
      ul_LeftMenu.DataSource = data.TABLE_MENU_ITEMs.ToList(dbParentID==ID);
      ul_LeftMenu.DataBind();

or 

      ul_LeftMenu.DataSource = data.TABLE_MENU_ITEMs.ToList().Where(dbParentID==ID);
      ul_LeftMenu.DataBind();
```

I just can find the right way to do this

This my db

```
    id          ParentID      Image            Yrl
    1   GENERAL     3       GENERA L.png    www.youtube.com
    2   PRODUCTS    3       Products.png    www.youtube.com
    3   CATEGORIES  3       Categories.png  www.google.com
    4   DISCOUNTS   3      Discounts.png    www.youtube.com
    5   ARTICLES    3       Articles.png    www.youtube.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close.

What you need to do, is something like this:

```
ul_LeftMenu.DataSource = data
    .TABLE_MENU_ITEMs
    .Where(x => x.dbParentID == ID);

ul_LeftMenu.DataBind();
```

When using Linq's `Where` you don't actually supply a true/false expression as you have tried to do. You actually need to supply a function that when *applied* to each item, will return true or false.

You can do this in a nice succinct readable way, by using a [Lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx) - such as :

```
x => x.dbParentID == ID
```

where `x` is the *each/current item*.

Comment: Does this Work in LINQ to SQL? I think not, because the Function cannot be executed on the server...

Comment: The lambda *function* is actually just treated as an *expression* in this case - and transformed into a comparable SQL query by LinqToSQL

Comment: @ChristianSauer, simple comparisons like this are allowed. This is similar to how Entity Framework operates: all operations are done on the sql server. You can't, however, use a custom function inside the lambda because the server does not know how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [Lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx).

```
ul_LeftMenu.DataSource = 
    data.TABLE_MENU_ITEMs.Where(x => x.dbParentID == ID).ToList();
```

or the query syntax

```
ul_LeftMenu.DataSource = (from item in data.TABLE_MENU_ITEMs
                          where item.dbParentID == ID
                          select item).ToList();
```

You might not need the `ToList()`. If you get an exception about some binding error, then you must use the `ToList()` to create a copy.

Look at [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) for some more information on what else you can use.